# Como tirar print de uma página web utilizando o backend rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Seria possível fazer isso?

Por exemplo:

Eu indico uma página para **minha aplicação**, e ela guarda uma **imagem** da página indicada. Uma print.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) para salvar uma imagem. Preparei a seguinte demonstração para você:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="welcome">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="screenshot"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var content = document.getElementById('welcome')
    , screenshot = document.getElementById('screenshot');

html2canvas(content, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        screenshot.appendChild(canvas);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle para visualizar.](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/8q2Y9/)

A técnica é bem simples: `#welcome` é o elemento que você deseja capturar uma screenshot; `#screenshot` é onde a mesma será exibida.

Para realizar o efeito que desejas, você deverá trabalhar em cumplicidade com o Rails. Você disse o seguinte:

> Eu indico uma página para minha aplicação, e ela guarda uma imagem da página indicada. Uma print.

Então, pela minha interpretação, você quer tirar a foto de uma página inteira. Para isso, você precisará consumir o corpo da tal página (elemento `body`) e utilizá-lo como referência no html2canvas (no caso, a variável `content` (no JavaScript) é a responsável por isso). Veja só:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://yourapp.com")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

render json: response.body
```

O código acima, baseado [neste aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804425/curl-on-ruby-on-rails), irá consumir todo o `body` da página solicitada. Depois, utilizando `render json: response.body`, você estará enviando, via JSON, este corpo para quem solicitar.

Em resumo, com um cenário:

1. Crie um `input` para você digitar de qual site você quer capturar a tela e um `button` para enviar a solicitação para o servidor (Rails);
2. Quando você ou algum usuário clicar no `button`, envie o valor do `input` para o servidor — [de maneira assíncrona, com AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) — e utilize ele para trabalhar com o `URI.parse`;
3. Então, o elemento `body`, que é o que você precisa para tirar foto da página, estará armazenado no fragmento `response.body` que está sendo devolvido para o cliente através do `render json`;
4. Por fim, na sucessão da sua requisição (do tipo `GET`, via AJAX), você chama a função em que o html2canvas está escopado e utilize a resposta da requisição para popular a variável `content`;

A linha que você deve seguir é mais ou menos essa. Existem algumas adaptações que você pode fazer ao longo do caminho, mas a ideia foi dada.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu buscava, estou iniciando e ainda não conheço estas bibliotecas, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A reposta para sua pergunta é muito complexa para ser detalhada, você precisa usar um serviço para gerenciamento de tarefas como o [SideKiq](http://sidekiq.org/) e integrá-lo com a gem [PhantomJS GEM](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem), lembrando que para isso você precisará ter instalado o [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). O PhantomJS irá permitir que você capture essas telas e para maiores informações, consulte: [Screen Capture Doc](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

Então através da GEM você poderá interagir usando:

```
require 'phantomjs'
Phantomjs.run('./path/to/script.js') # => retorna stdout
```